# Have iptables send an email on DROP

Tags: iptables

I'd like to invoke sending an e-mail (or running a particular script, if that would be possible) when a certain iptables DROP rule is being run. (For instance, when I'm blocking an IP after 5 failed SSH logins, I'd like to run `mail -s "SSH Blocked" info@example.com` or something similar. Is there a way to directly have iptables execute this?

If not, then I guess I'd need to scan the logs with an external tool and then send out emails. Any recommended tool for this? Please note that I'm using `systemd` so I am using `journalctl` and not old fashioned log files.

Comment: I think you might want to look into fail2ban

Comment: On a typical Internet facing system, doing this you will likely result in you receiving far more email than you want.

Comment: fail2ban or denyhosts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have been using for more that 5 years to alert sysadmins to this type of (and many others) event, is ossec hids (http://www.ossec.net) funded by Trend Micro.

Ossec does blocking and alerting by scanning logs in real-time. You can install it on the local machine, or on another server. It can function as a central syslog server. Most features can be tailored to your needs. For log aggregation and inspection (required in PCI environments), I have not found many other applications that surpass what Ossec offers.